# Can't delete my files

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions

For the life of me, I can't delete folders and files from my second harddrive.

Does anyone know how to overcome this security "feature"?

I have followed guides online, and they generally say, set ownership, and set permissions to full Control.

I have even enabled the administrator account (my own account is an admin too), and tried it from there but no luck.

The screenshots below are me trying from the "adminstrator" login. Owner and permissions set.

It just keeps telling me I need permission from administrator. I AM ADMINISTRATOR ! (My pc is called Paul-PC)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should be able to modify the target within that `Possible Duplicate` answer to delete your files. As always, please proceed with caution and ensure that the files/folders you wish to delete aren't critical assets.

Comment: @Run5k To clarify, your suggestion is to delete the folders from command prompt while in recovery mode? I'll try it out if an easier method does not surface. Thanks

Comment: Yes, although that method is a bit more complex than others, in my experience it has consistently succeeded under similar circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Try running CMD.EXE as an administrator and change the path (Drive and directory)to the folder you want to delete file from and try deleting using the DEL command. If you need help for the DEL command, enter DEL /? or HELP DEL on the command line.

This worked for me when I had the same problem.